# Convert PHP String To Array

Tags: php, arrays

My String is a comma separated list of id numbers e.g.

> 81234567,81234569,44489000,123,9585,1023

I want to convert each part to an array, without the comma, so i can run a foreach, to query an API for each reference number, what is the easiest way of achieving this?

Comment: `explode` http://ch1.php.net/explode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode):

```
$parts = explode(',', '1234567,81234569,44489000,123,9585,1023');
print_r($parts);

Array
(
    [0] => 1234567
    [1] => 81234569
    [2] => 44489000
    [3] => 123
    [4] => 9585
    [5] => 1023
)
```

Comment: And, if you want to convert array to string.
You can use http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Great thanks for That! I now for each of those id's want to perform an action (query API and echo response), how do i use foreach to achieve this, or should i use while?

Comment: `foreach` is generally preferred over `while` but both would work for you.